# Saving a TextView (DropDownList) to Database in Android

Tags: android

I have **TextViews (DropDownList)** and **EditTexts** in my activity.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+DropDownList/tv_SubBrand"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+DropDownList/tv_InfoType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_Remarks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'd like to save the user input to my database but I'm having a problem in my Textviews because it is a DropDownList where in it has checkboxes inside the DropDownList and it **can handle multiple options**. Also, I can't cast it to OnCreate.

Is there any solution aside from using SharedPreferences? Can I resolve it when I use ArrayList? If yes, can you show me on how to do it?

Comment: Maybe use `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: Can you show some codes regarding SharedPreferences? I don't know how to use it

Comment: Sure, let me get it for ya ;-)

Comment: You can store multiple data. Please check my answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SharedPreferences. There'a nice thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) for it. With it, you can save the number in a Preference file (visible only for the current application and not in the file system). Like this one:

```
private final String PREFS_NAME  = "savefile";
private final String KEY_SUBBRAND    = "subb";
String strWithTheInput = ""
String strSavedValue = "";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

*//To put the phone in the file*

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString(KEY_SUBBRAND, strWithTheInput);
editor.commit();
```

*//To retrieve the number*

```
strSavedValue = sharedPreferences.getString("subb", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SharedPreferences` in `onPause` for current `Activity` as below and send the data to other activities as below:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() 
{
  super.onPause(); 
  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();  
  editor.putString("SearchText",edt.getText().toString());
      editor.putString("Text1",<Your TextView1>.getText().toString());
      editor.putString("Text2",<Your TextView2>.getText().toString());
  editor.commit();

}
```

and in other two Activities, get the data from Shared Preferences as below:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", 0);
 String edtText = preferences.getString("SearchText","");
 String strTextView1 = preferences.getString("Text1","");
 String strTextView2 = preferences.getString("Text2","");
```